# Nissan MAF Volts to Grams per Second Conversion?

Tags: nissan, maf

So my 99 Nissan Almera GA16DE 1.6L ( Euro Sentra ) is only OBDI, and only provides a voltage PID for the MAF.

Anyone know of a conversion from volts to grams per second?

Comment: Work it out : take readings of voltage at various rpm and then calculate the airflow at each rpm ie volume delivered per stroke - you will need to account for air losses and it will get more complcated if it is turbo...

Comment: I'm seeing "stuff" which shows this is a logarithmic function (non-linear) ... but nothing I'd call official. And then I've only found anything which shows just for idle, which is 1.1-1.5vdc, which is 2.0-6.0 g/s. [Here's the forum I pulled it from](https://my350z.com/forum/tuning/337205-maf-voltage-vs-air-flow-rate-data-anyone.htm), if that helps.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That sounds about right, 1 gramme of air is about 1 litre at ambient T and P. Then idle at 800 rpm is about 13 revs/sec & a 4 stroke so 13/4 is just over 3 intake strokes per second i.e. about 3 litres...